# How to print multiple characters

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I want to print Multiple characters from a txt file. Example:
I have a test.txt , inside a long string

```
HELLOWORD HELLOWORD HELLOWORD HELLOWORD HELLOWORD HELLOWORD HELLOWORD HELLOWORD HELLOWORD HELLOWORD
```

I want to print the first byte `H` then then skip 5 bytes and print the `O` then skip 5 bytes and print `L` until the end.

I tried `cat test.txt | cut -b 1,7,13...` but I want to know if there is an other command to do it without giving the position of each byte knowing that I have to skip 5 bytes and print the byte after.

Comment: Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: HOLDO..........

Comment: Edit your question and add it there. Do not put it in the comments where it can get lost.